# JSON data from file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, treeview

I have written a jquery to get data by assigning a hard coded value to variable.

My requirement is to get the same data from a json file, can anyone help me with this code in doing that. Please find the code below:

```
$(function () {
  var jsonCalendarTreeStructure = [
    {
      text: 'Years',
      nodes: [
        {
          text: '2013',
          type: 'Y',
          nodes: [
            {
              text: '13-Q1',
              type: 'Q',
            },
            {
              text: '13-01',
              type: 'M',
            },
            {
              text: '13-02',
            },
            {
              text: '13-03',
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  $('#Dyanmic').treeview({
    data: jsonCalendarTreeStructure,
  });
}
```

Comment: grammar fixes, code formatted

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('URL to JSON file', function(data){
   //use data
});
```

You can use jquery getJSON.

Comment: Am also Using the below command for check box is it possible to add along with the  above code $('#Dyanmic').on('nodeChecked', function (event, data) {
     if (data.type=="Y")
      yearFilter(data.text);
     else if (data.type=="Q")
      quarterFilter(data.text);
      else if (data.type=="M")
      monthFilter(data.text);
      
                });

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be available in json in this format:

```
[  
   {  
      "text":"Years",
      "nodes":[  
         {  
            "text":"2013",
            "type":"Y",
            "nodes":[  
               {  
                  "text":"13-Q1",
                  "type":"Q"
               },
               {  
                  "text":"13-01",
                  "type":"M"
               },
               {  
                  "text":"13-02"
               },
               {  
                  "text":"13-03"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

With whatever method (ajax, for example), you can then deserialise it:

```
$.get('url', function (data) {
    $('#Dyanmic').treeview({
    data: data,
});
```

Comment: I need to add the below code to the above function, Can you please guide me
                $('#Dyanmic').on('nodeChecked', function (event, data) {
     if (data.type=="Y")
      yearFilter(data.text);
     else if (data.type=="Q")
      quarterFilter(data.text);
      else if (data.type=="M")
      monthFilter(data.text);
                });

Comment: Can you confirm that the `data` in the callback contains the json we mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it is JSON and the above mentioned function is for checkbox

Comment: Please edit the question and explain precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a front end application, where i am trying to build up a tree structured filter by getting data for it from JSON file, you could find my code in the above were i am getting data by hard coding the JSON data to a variable, now my requirement is to get it from the JSON File and call it over the body tag, the code which you have said does not work or i am missing something